# How do i get the drawing to loop automatically with out need for user input scrolling?

Tags: game-design, sdl, game-loop, sdl2

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <time.h> 
#include <iomanip> 
#include <SDL.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include "screen.h" 
#include "Stars.h" 
#include "Allstars.h" 


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    //seeding random number generator


    srand(time(NULL));

    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    /***CREATING SDL WINDOW***/
    /***CREATING RENDERER & TEXTURE***/
    /***CREATING A BUFFER***/

    Screen screen1;
    screen1.init();

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    /***GAME LOOP***/

    /*UPDATING buffer with texture information*/

    Allstars allstars1;

    while (true) {
        int num=0;
        screen1.screenClear();
        allstars1.updateStarPosition();


        // Allstars class to retrieve  m_pstars from the Allstars class into the main function.

        const Stars * const pStars = allstars1.getStars();

        for (int i = 0; i < allstars1.NSTARS; i++) {
            Stars star = pStars[i];

            // here is where i tried to loop each star back to the bottom of the screen  when they reached the top of the screen.

            if(num>3 && star.m_y_star<-0.97 && star.m_y_star>-1){

                    star.m_y_star=0.99;
                    star.m_x_star= star.m_x_star;

                }

//each star is given a random location by giving co-ordinates: m_x_star & m_y_star a random value using a function in Stars.h
// You can't get negative co-ordinates on the screen so we map from [-1,1] to [0 to SCREEN_WIDTH and 0 to SCREEN_HEIGHT]

            int x = (star.m_x_star + 1) * ((Screen::SCREEN_WIDTH) / 2);
            int y = (star.m_y_star + 1) * ((Screen::SCREEN_HEIGHT) / 2);
            screen1.setPixel(x, y, 128, 0, 255);
        }

        /*UPDATED USED TO UPDATE TEXTURE and RENDERER and PRESENT DRAWING ON SCREEN*/
        screen1.update();

        /* Check for messages and events
         */

        //Quitting SDL through clicking 'x' button event
        if (screen1.processEvents() == false) {
            break;

        }
        num++;
    }
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    /***FREEING MEMORY & QUITTING SDL***/
    screen1.close();
    return 0;
}
//------------------------------END OF MAIN----------------------------------------
```

I tried to get use a for loop to change the vertical position of the star once it draws close to the top of the window but that doesn't seem to influence the program. Stars (purple dots) seem to drift off the screen and don't appear from the bottom of the screen again. No errors occur and i have incorporated checks to prevent the stars being plotted off of the screen. Can someone help me make these purple dots loop infinitely without the need for scrolling.

[image]

Comment: What's the purpose of `num`?

Comment: Also the condition of `star.m_y_star<-0.97 && star.m_y_star>-1` seems weird to me - why this range? What does it stand for? And is it ever `true`? What does debugging tell you?

Comment: /num/ counts the number of loops in the game loop  to give a time lag so that the inital positions of the trailing dots dont get overwritten (Num can be ignored).

Comment: the range of m_y_star and m_x_star is [-1 to 1] as they are there positions are given by the equation m_x/y_ star= (2*rand()/RAND_MAX)-1. This is then mapped to the screen width and height in the main() function. -1 is technically off the top of the screen so i used -0.79 as a cut off point. The speed at which each dot is moving is 0.001 in both co-ordinates. This was acheived by creating  the updateStarPosition() method.

Comment: I produced this code by using the following tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cyAvUaPcvss

Comment: Well that tutorial is not particularly great (both the design and old-style C++ are not ideal). But you still haven't told me if that condition ever evaluates to `true` - that's what you need to check for first (using either a debugger or a simple print statement)

Comment: I don't know how to use the debugger  but i can say that i modified the conditional if statement to  the following: if(star.m_y_star<-0.9 && star.m_y_star>-1){

     star.m_y_star=0.99;
     star.m_x_star= star.m_x_star;
    }

Comment: I also inputted a print statement inside the loop and and it runs as expected.  A statement is printed after each dot reaches the value of -0.97 for the m_y_co-ordinate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume two things:

1. The constructor of `Allstars allstars1;` initializes the random positions of all the `Stars` contained therein.
2. `allstars1.updateStarPosition();` translates the current set of stars vertically in the range `[-1, 1]` by some very small amount, say 0.001, as you say.

From there, as I understand it, you want to loop through all your stars snapping the y-position of any in the range `(-0.97, -1)` to `0.99` *while maintaining their x-position*.

---

First, move the declaration and initialization of `int num = 0` out of the `while(true)` loop because setting it to 0 each loop means:

```
if(num>3 && star.m_y_star<-0.97 && star.m_y_star>-1)
```

is *always false*. However, if you still want to use it then reset `num = 0;` inside that `num>3` y-position range check. Although I do see in your comments that you've since changed the condition for the better.

---

The constant pointer to constant data means that *nothing* `pStars` points to can be changed.

```
const Stars * const pStars = allstars1.getStars();
```

Moreover,

```
Stars star = pStars[i];
```

makes a **copy** of your `allstars1` element, which means anything you do to it will not affect anything in `allstars1`

Both these statements together mean any y-position snapping you do in the `for` loop only affects the **copies** of `allstars1` elements, and therefore the results only last one frame.  This is why you only see a line of stars along the bottom of the screen instead of scrolling stars.

---

The quick and dirty solution is simply to remove the constant-data qualifier, that is change:

```
const Stars * const pStars = allstars1.getStars();
```

to this:

```
Stars * const pStars = allstars1.getStars();
```

Then instead of instantiating a copy for each pStar[i] element, just use it directly:

```
if(num>3 && pStar[i].m_y_star<-0.97 && pStar[i].m_y_star>-1){
    pStar[i].m_y_star=0.99;
//  pStar[i].m_x_star= pStar[i].m_x_star;    // unnecessary self-assignment
}
```

The self-assignment line is unnecessary; the x-coordinate is constant whether or not you self-assign it.

The same applies here too:

```
int x = (pStar[i].m_x_star + 1) * ((Screen::SCREEN_WIDTH) / 2);
int y = (pStar[i].m_y_star + 1) * ((Screen::SCREEN_HEIGHT) / 2);
```

---

Given that you are using a constant raw pointer to non-constant data you might as well move your `pStars` pointer outside your `while(true)` loop. That will save you an assignment each frame.

---

As a general note look into [SDL_GetTicks()](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetTicks) instead of `<time.h>`. Also look into c++ passing by reference, and operator[] overloading, they'll save you a lot of pointer debugging headaches in the future.

Comment: Thanks TOM, i've just seen your reply now. I got the code to work yesterday by moving my  ''if-statement' within the allstars1.updateStarPosition method. This updates the position of every star before they are re-instantiated in the main function.  I think putting the if-statement within the game loop meant that the m_y_star values would keep take that value but not be updated. From what you have pointed out, the code i've written is somewhat inefficient. I'll make  these changes and report on the results.

Comment: Good solution @The Ace, you get a cleaner main loop, and better object encapsulation. Also consider mapping `Stars` `x` and `y` coordinates to screen coordinates on their initialization. That allows changing the (-0.97, -1) check/snap to that of screen dimensions, saving hundreds of x,y calculations each frame. Plus, it allows for `int` instead of `float` or `double` when translating the star position without worrying about rounding errors using 0.001 increments, which will happen using SDL_RenderDrawPoint which takes `int`s. I'm glad you solved it, there's no need to report on further results